# How to run a function everytime an observable gets subscribed

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I've only recently started using Rx so if this isn't the best way to do what I'm trying to do please correct it.

**Goal:** Having an observable that hits an API (with Retrofit), and everytime it does it saves the response to local storage, but without having to do it everytime I subscribe to it, since I will do it in multiple places.

Having something like this:

```
myRetrofit.create(MyInterface::class.java).hitEndpoint()
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
myRetrofit.create(MyInterface::class.java).hitEndpoint()
        .intercept { storageUtils.saveItem("key", it) }
```

**Question:** How do I run a function before an observable gets subscribed to?

Comment: I think you could use `doOnSubscribe()`

Comment: @ChadBingham, but how can I access the response in `doOnSubscribe()` ?

Comment: Check out the [`doOnX`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doOnNext-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-) operators. You probably need `doOnNext` or `doOnSuccess` depending on what the return type of `hitEndpoint()` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @akarnokd 's comment, I just used `.doOnNext { }`.

The other solutions would have worked as well but this was was the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is using an [`ObservableTransformer<T>`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableTransformer.html).

A sketch of a solution would look something like this:

```
class LocalStorageComposer<T>: ObservableTransformer<T,T>(private val localStorage : LocalStorage) {
    override fun apply(upstream: Observable<T>) {
        return upstream.map {
            localStorage.store(it)
            it
        }
    }
}
```

And then you consume it like this:

```
someApi.getAllData()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .compose(LocalStorageComposer(localStorage))
       .subscribe //etc
```

It would work better if `LocalStorageComposer` was something you could inject using a DI framework like Dagger 2. Effectively, it allows you to have the mapping to local storage as an extra step in your API calls without referencing it explicitly.

Another thing to look at is the caching for OkHttp (link [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)) which may better fit your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to do something before subscribing to the event. In that case, simply using the `map` operator will do the job.
It would look something like:

```
myRetrofit.create(MyInterface::class.java)
.map{
//operation, you can access the response as "it"
it
}.hitEndpoint()
```